# Android Room + AsyncTask

Tags: android-asynctask, android-room

My team have developed a new Android app which makes extensive use of Room.

I am unsure whether we are using AsyncTask correctly.

We have had to wrap all calls to insert/update/delete in AsyncTasks which results in a huge number of AsyncTasks.  All the calls into Room are from background services.  There is no direct Room access from activities or fragments - they get everything via LiveData.

An example call to insert a row:

```
AsyncTask.execute(() -> myModelDAO.insertInstance(myModel));
```

With this in the DAO:

```
@Insert
void insertInstance(MyModel model);
```

Answer (score 24):

To complete @CommonsWare answer, you can use the [Executor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) class to execute Room queries into a background thread.

```
Executor myExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
myExecutor.execute(() -> {
   myModelDAO.insertInstance(myModel)
});
```

Google showed an example on their Android Architecture Components [guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html).

Comment: does this work equivalent to AsyncTask? what's the benefit of using it over asynctask, can you explain?

Answer (score 7):

> All the calls into Room are from background services

Then you should not be using `AsyncTask`. `AsyncTask` is *only* for when you want to do work on the main application thread after doing background work, and that is almost never the case with a service. Use something else (thread, thread pool, RxJava, etc.). This has nothing specific to do with Room.

Comment: insert query can lock android UI thread and it is not permitted to do so. We need to put insert inside background async or RX

Comment: @MunishThakur: Yes, but there are many ways of doing asynchronous work that does not involve an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Right, with lamba and kotlin support eveything is shorter event Async task also is of one Liner :-)

 AsyncTask.execute({ // code to Exceute })

Answer (score 1):

```
AsyncTask.execute(() -> myModelDAO.insertInstance(myModel));
```

Looking like incorrect you can use Simple Thread/Threadpool/Schedulers etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback like `Consumer<List<object>>callback`.
For example:

```
roomManger.getAllUsertById(user.getId(), this, new Consumer<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(List<Product> listOfUser) {
                users.addAll(listOfUser)}
```